# Wrong cursor style when TinyMCE is rendered into a modal

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-5, chakra-ui

I'm rendering TinyMCE editor into a chakra-ui modal.

When hovering the content edit area, cursor is `pointer` instead of `text` (visually, I couldn't find any cursor css property when inspecting).

Any idea how to ensure the cursor remains of `text` style same as with all textarea element and TinyMCE rendered outside modals?